# How to filter a column according to values of another column in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

Suppose that my query is 'A' for the following table. I want to find any value of 'c_index' corresponding to 'A', and then get all the rows of the table which have the corresponding values of 'c_index'.

| Node Name | c_index |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| D | 3 |
| C | 4 |
| E | 4 |

Values of 'c_index' corresponding to 'A' are {1, 2}. So the desired result of the filter is:

| Node Name | c_index |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| C | 2 |

How can I do this filtration in Tableau?

What I tried is:
Defined a filter on 'c_index' (i.e. drag and drop 'c_index' to the filter shelf). And then I tried to define the condition for the filter as: [Node Name] = 'A'.

But it throws an error: "The formula must be an aggregate calculation or refer only to this field".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Join the (data) table with itself on the column which you want to return linked values.  In the example `c_index`.

Now there will two same data sets in your data pane.

Add `node` from first dataset to filter, `node` from second dataset to view and `c_index` from anyone to view.  You'll get what you desire.  See GIF below

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and response. Just one more quick question: what type of join should do?

Comment: And from the GIF, it seems that it does not work properly when you are filtering for B.

Comment: Full join in tableau.  If you see carefully it is filtering correctly for B (A B B D).  IF you are unable to join please tell.  Since you are joining table with itself results will be same for all joins. If it served the purpose please accept and upvote as usually desired on SO.

Comment: I did it. It just does not show it for some reason!

Comment: Try first accepting it, it help you gain some reputation and then try upvoting it.